# Powershell ISE recognised the cmdlets but not in powershell console

Tags: windows, powershell

In the powershell ISE we can run the cmdlets which are loaded from the modules defined in the script . But the same script is not working from the powershell console.

Please let me know how to make it work in console same as ISE.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you set the console to run as Administrator? I've found the ISE has a load of problems when run as Admin so I typically run it as a user. Perhaps that is affecting your modules? Otherwise please elaborate on "not working" - are you getting an error? Is it just not loading?

Comment: Could you be needing to use the `Import-Module` cmdlet to load them in the shell?  What modules are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

One thing to check out is your profile script.  The ISE and the Console use different filespecs for the profile script.  You can edit the profile script using your favorite editor, like this:

```
> notepad $profile
```

If your ISE $profile defines some things that your Console $profile does not, then that may be the reason for the different behavior.